# table view Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout

what I'm doing here? I'm trying to build an Instagram clone and in my home view controller that what should posts show up. I make navigation with a table view and that table view has 2 cell with the different identifier. cell number 1 it's a header that brings data from users table to my username label and profile image. and cell number 2 its for posts its should bring post data like image and caption. I use firebase database. the problem is my layout is a not show like what i want and its give this error:

```
2017-12-31 00:00:31.920010+0300 Instgram Clone[2165:463944] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029af40 UIImageView:0x7fdc8765e940.height == 375   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000284ba0 UIButton:0x7fdc874433e0.height == 30   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000285460 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fdc8765e940]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc8765e110 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002854b0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdc8765e940]-(7)-[UIStackView:0x7fdc87442fd0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002855a0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fdc87442fd0]-(7)-[UIView:0x7fdc87441230]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000285640 V:[UIView:0x7fdc87441230]-(7)-[UIButton:0x7fdc87441410'\U2665\Ufe0e 15 Likes']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000285690 V:[UIButton:0x7fdc87441410'\U2665\Ufe0e 15 Likes']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fdc87442870'What a. Great day']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002857d0 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc87442870'What a. Great day']-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7fdc87442550'Be the first one share a ...']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002858c0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc8765e110.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7fdc87442b50'2 Day ago'.bottom + 12   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000285910 V:[UIButton:0x7fdc87442550'Be the first one share a ...']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fdc87442b50'2 Day ago']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029c9d0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fdc87442fd0.top == _UILayoutSpacer:0x6000001c8160'UISV-alignment-spanner'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000281bd0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fdc87442fd0.centerY == UIButton:0x7fdc874433e0.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029c840 'UISV-spanning-boundary' _UILayoutSpacer:0x6000001c8160'UISV-alignment-spanner'.top <= UIButton:0x7fdc874433e0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000285cd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc8765e110.height == 58.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000284ba0 UIButton:0x7fdc874433e0.height == 30   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
```

just for knowledge :

postcell = header of view

imagecell = the post of view

[header cell constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwuMh.png)

[post cell constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKq1W.png)

[Continue with post cell constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymfFw.png)

[this image to my result layout when the running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odupQ.png)

my new error message when I fix the content view high :

```
2018-01-01 02:56:25.304650+0300 Instgram Clone[1217:35419] Month 13 is out of bounds
2018-01-01 02:56:25.312217+0300 Instgram Clone[1217:35419] Month 13 is out of bounds
2018-01-01 02:56:25.338368+0300 Instgram Clone[1217:35424] Month 13 is out of bounds
2018-01-01 02:56:25.343009+0300 Instgram Clone[1217:35431] Month 13 is out of bounds
2018-01-01 02:56:25.374175+0300 Instgram Clone[1217:35323] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483750 UIImageView:0x7fdf61548390.height == 36   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483d90 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdf61548390]-(8.5)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdf615481a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483de0 V:|-(12)-[UIImageView:0x7fdf61548390]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdf615481a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000482530 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdf615481a0.height == 57   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483750 UIImageView:0x7fdf61548390.height == 36   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: The height constraint on the Button conflicts with another constraint. It's better to look at the layout in IB to see which one it is. In the constraints list you will be able to see the conflict. if possible post a snap of the layout screen with the constraints on the left side.

Comment: You can also use [wtfautolayout.com](http://wtfautolayout.com) - It seems that your image has a height of 375 but your whole cell is only 58.5 high

Comment: john elemans,  thanks for the reply I but my constraints . and what is the (IB)?

Comment: Paulw11, thanks for the reply my image has 375 height and my cell has 587 height it's not the problem

Comment: No, your content view has 58.5 height; see the last constraint in the message

Comment: Paulw11, i change the row high for the table view i but it automatic  and the layout  work fine but is show me another problem (Month 13 is out of bounds) with  (Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints)